# Problema com setState em React Native: "Can't call 'setState' on a component that is not yet mounted."

Tags: javascript, mobile, react, react-native, app

tudo bem?
Eu sou iniciante em React Native e nesse app que eu estou fazendo eu não consigo chamar o 'setState' no método que eu criei. O nome do método que eu criei se chama includingMed() e eu chamo ele aqui

```js
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isVisible: false,
      newMed: [],
      medName: "",
      medInitHour: null,
      medTimes: null
    }
  }

  addMed = () => { 
    if(!this.state.medName.trim() || !this.state.medTimes){
      Alert.alert('Dados inválidos!','Verifique se todos os campos estão preenchidos.');
      return
    }

    try {
      this.setState({
        newMed: this.state.newMed.push({
          medName: this.state.medName,
          medInitHour: this.state.medInitHour,
          medTimes: this.state.medTimes
        }),
        medInitHour: null,
        medTimes: null,
        medName: ""
      });
      var include = new MedList();
      include.includingMed(this.state.newMed);

      this.setState({newMed: []});

      ToastAndroid.show('Medicamento Adicionado!', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    }catch (ex){
      ToastAndroid.show('Falha ao adicionar. Erro: '+ex, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    }
  }
```

E aqui embaixo é toda a programação dele que é onde o setState() falha ao ser executado e me retorna aquela mensagem:

```js
includingMed = newMed => {
    const meds = [...this.state.meds];
    meds.push({
      id: Math.random(),
      medName: newMed.medName,
      medInitHour: newMed.medInit,
      medTimes: newMed.medTimes
    });

    this.setState({ meds });
  }
```

Por gentileza, eu agradeceria muito se alguém puder me ajudar nesse app, é a minha primeira vez kkk
Obrigado, abraço!!

Comment: Olá Pablo, coloque o código completo do seu arquivo, para facilitar na análise do erro!

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar assim:  this.setState(this.state);

Answer (score -1):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ExpoConfigView } from '@expo/samples';
//import Meds from '../components/Meds'
import {
  FlatList,
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import Meds from '../components/Meds';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';


export default class MedList extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Remédios',
  };

  state = {
    meds: [
      { id: Math.random(), medName: 'Diclofenaco', medInitHour: 0, medTimes: 3 },
      { id: Math.random(), medName: 'Aspirina', medInitHour: 0, medTimes: 4 },
      { id: Math.random(), medName: 'Cimegripe', medInitHour: 0, medTimes: 2 },
      { id: Math.random(), medName: 'Diclofenaco', medInitHour: 0, medTimes: 3 },
      { id: Math.random(), medName: 'Aspirina', medInitHour: 0, medTimes: 4 },
      { id: Math.random(), medName: 'Cimegripe', medInitHour: 0, medTimes: 2 },
      { id: Math.random(), medName: 'Diclofenaco', medInitHour: 0, medTimes: 3 },
      { id: Math.random(), medName: 'Aspirina', medInitHour: 0, medTimes: 4 },
      { id: Math.random(), medName: 'Cimegripe', medInitHour: 0, medTimes: 2 },
      { id: Math.random(), medName: 'Diclofenaco', medInitHour: 0, medTimes: 3 },
      { id: Math.random(), medName: 'Aspirina', medInitHour: 0, medTimes: 4 },
      { id: Math.random(), medName: 'Cimegripe', medInitHour: 0, medTimes: 2 }
    ]
  }

  includingMed = newMed => {
    const meds = [...this.state.meds];
    meds.push({
      id: Math.random(),
      medName: newMed.medName,
      medInitHour: newMed.medInit,
      medTimes: newMed.medTimes
    });

    this.setState({ meds });
  }

  render() {
    /* Go ahead and delete ExpoConfigView and replace it with your
     * content, we just wanted to give you a quick view of your config */
    //return <ExpoConfigView />;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <Text>Ainda vou colocar alguma coisa aqui</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.list}>
          <FlatList data={this.state.meds}
            keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Meds {...item} />}>
          </FlatList>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#aaa',
    padding: 30,
    margin: 10,
    width: '75%',
    color: '#fff'
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(113, 165, 237, 0.4)'
  },
  list: {
    marginBottom: 40
  }
});
```

É nesse arquivo onde estou tendo problemas com o setState()